# jquery auto height animate toggle button

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a box that can be expanding auto-height by click button.
The box have height 30px as default, when I click the button the box expanding height and it depends how content quantity. Also the button to be toggle.

Can anyone help me how to Jquery ?

This is my code below.

```
<div class="box">
  text <br>text <br>text <br>text <br>text <br>text <br>  text <br>text <br>text <br>text <br>text <br>text <br>
</div>
<a href="#" class="btnMore">button</a>

.box { height:30px; overflow:hidden; }
```

Comment: put your jquery code and also refresh your question what exactly you need.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if there is a better way, try

```
$('.btnMore').click(function () {
    var x = $(this).prev().stop(true);
    x.animate({
        height: x.prop('scrollHeight')
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/g2C5W/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    var trg = $("#box"), // The target container
        preHeight = 200; // The initial height

    trg.css('height', preHeight); // Set the initial height on page load

    $('.link').on('click', function(){
        var curHeight = trg.height();

        if(preHeight == curHeight){
            var xHeight = 'auto';
            $(this).text('Shrink');
        } else {
            var xHeight = preHeight;
            $(this).text('Stretch');
        }

        var trgHeight = trg.css('height', xHeight).height();
        trg.height(curHeight).animate({ height: trgHeight }, 600, function() { trg.css('height', xHeight); });
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/effone/w82Ve/

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery code

```
$('.btnMore').click(function(){
var $this = $(this);
if($this.data('expanded') == "yes"){
    $this.data('expanded',"no");
    $('.box').animate({height:'30px'});
}else{
    $this.data('expanded',"yes");
    $('.box').css({height:'auto'});
}
});
```

Check this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/midoalone/37Tg5/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$('.btnMore').click(function () {
    var el = $('.box'),
    curHeight = el.height(),
    autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
    el.height(curHeight).animate({
        height: autoHeight == curHeight ? "30px" : autoHeight
    }, 1000);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cpS62/)**

Answer (score 0):

For changing the height to Auto from 30px, use this code

```
$('#test').click(function() {   
    autoHeight = $('.box').css('height', 'auto').height();
    $('.box').animate({height:autoHeight}, 500);
}
```

The code below will toggle you div's height between 30px and auto if you want to do that use this code

```
$('#test').clickToggle(function() {   
    autoHeight = $('.box').css('height', 'auto').height();
    $('.box').animate({height:autoHeight}, 500);
},
function() {
    autoHeight = $('.box').css('height', '30px').height();
    $('.box').animate({height:autoHeight}, 500);
});
```